# How to convert an {Mx1} cell array of {1xN cell} arrays into a {1xN} cell array of {Mx1 cell} arrays?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Suppose that `C` is a cell array with shape *M* × 1 (i.e., `size(C)` returns [*M* 1]), and that each element of `C` is in turn a cell array with shape 1 × *N*.

I often want to convert such a cell array to a new cell array `D` having shape 1 × *N*, with elements being cell arrays with shape *M* × 1, and such that `C{i}{j}` equals `D{j}{i}` for all 0 < *i* ≤ *M*, and 0 < *j* ≤ *N*.

I use the following monstrosity for this

```
D = arrayfun(@(j) arrayfun(@(i) C{i}{j}, (1:M)', 'un', 0), 1:N, 'un', 0);
```

but the need for this operation arises often enough (after all, it's sort of a "cell array transpose") that I thought I'd ask:

> **is there a more standard way to do this operation?**

Note that the desired `D` is different from

```
E = cat(2, C{:});
```

or, equivalently,

```
E = cat(1, D{:});
```

The `E` above is a two-dimensional (*M* × *N*) cell array, whereas both `C` and `D` are one-dimensional cell arrays of one-dimensional cell arrays. Of course, conversion of `E` back to either `C` or `D` is also another often needed operation (this sort of thing is never-ending with MATLAB), but I'll leave it for another post.

---

<sub>The motivation behind this question goes far beyond the problem described above. It turns out that a *huge* fraction of my MATLAB code, and an even larger fraction of my MATLAB programming *time and effort*, are devoted to this *essentially unproductive* chore of converting data from one format to another. Of course, format conversion is unavoidable when doing any kind of computational work, but with MATLAB I find myself doing it a lot more, or at least having to work *a lot harder* at it, than when I work in other systems (e.g., *Mathematica* or Python/NumPy). My hope is that by building up my repertoire of MATLAB "format conversion tricks" I will be able to bring down to a more reasonable level the fraction of my MATLAB programming time that I have to devote to format conversion.</sub>

---

P.S. The following code constructs a `C` like the one described above, for *M* = 5 and *N* = 2.

```
uc = ['A':'Z'];
randstr = @() uc(randi(26, [1 4]));
M = 5;
rng(0);  % keep example reproducible
C = arrayfun(@(i) {randstr() i}, 1:M, 'un', 0)';

% C = 
%     {1x2 cell}
%     {1x2 cell}
%     {1x2 cell}
%     {1x2 cell}
%     {1x2 cell}
% >> cat(1, C{:});
% ans = 
%     'VXDX'    [1]
%     'QCHO'    [2]
%     'YZEZ'    [3]
%     'YMUD'    [4]
%     'KXUY'    [5]
%     

N = 2;
D = arrayfun(@(j) arrayfun(@(i) C{i}{j}, (1:M)', 'un', 0), 1:N, 'un', 0);

% D = 
%     {5x1 cell}    {5x1 cell}
```

Comment: +1 for well formulated answer and reproducible code. I don't think the double-`arrayfun` approach is so much of a monstrosity

Comment: @LuisMendo: imagine if you had to write something like that every time you needed a matrix transpose.  It's a monstrosity for me, because I need this operation so often.  Of course, I may be able to write a function to facilitate things, but before doing this, I thought I'd ask to see if there's already a suitable built-in alternative.

Comment: @kjo: Is this just an intermediate step and your actual problem is how to transpose your cell array `C` to a 1-by-5 cell containing five 2-by-1 cells? Also perhaps a different data structure is called for. Maybe a `struct`?

Comment: @horchler: as I said in my small-print, this is a recurring situation; it arises in many diverse contexts.  At some earlier time the transposition problem you mention may have been one of such contexts, but not at the moment.

Comment: @kjo I agree with you on that. But a cell array of cell arrays is a slightly convoluted structure, so it seems normal to me that you need such a complicate expression to "transpose" it. It's not transpose, it's more to turn it inside out, so to speak. If you had a 2D cell array instead of nested cell arrays you could simply use tranpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little trick using [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), which actually works with cell array inputs – the key is to first expand `C` into a 5-by-2 cell array (equivalent to `cell(5,2)`).

```
% Your example to produce C
uc = ['A':'Z'];
randstr = @() uc(randi(26, [1 4]));
M = 5;
rng(0);  % Keep example reproducible
C = arrayfun(@(i) {randstr() i}, 1:M, 'un', 0)';

% D = num2cell(reshape([C{:}],[N M]).',[1 M])
D = num2cell(reshape([C{:}],[size(C{1},2) size(C,1)]).',[1 size(C,1)])
```

or more simply

```
D = num2cell(cat(1,C{:}),1)
```

where `D{:}` returns:

```
ans = 

    'VXDX'
    'QCHO'
    'YZEZ'
    'YMUD'
    'KXUY'


ans = 

    [1]
    [2]
    [3]
    [4]
    [5]
```

The inverse operation to go from `D` back to `C` can be accomplished via:

```
% C = num2cell(reshape([D{:}],[N M]),[M N])
C = num2cell(reshape([D{:}],[size(D{1},1) size(D,2)]),[size(D,2) size(D{1},1)])
```

or

```
C = num2cell(cat(2,D{:}),2)
```

Thus you might be able to create a function like the following that would work in either direction:

```
transpose_cells = @(C)num2cell(cat(isrow(C)+1,C{:}),isrow(C)+1);
isequal(transpose_cells(transpose_cells(C)),C)
```